# Handling errors in API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I know this question has been asked before, but I am looking for replies specific to my situation.  Essentially, I have built an API.  This API has an unprotected login route

```
Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
```

I am using JWT for authentication, and this login route expects an email an password.  The function looks something like the following

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'), 200);
}
```

So if the credentials are wrong, it returns a 401.  If the application is unable to create the token it returns a 500 response.  If the token is successfully created, it returns a 200.

From the outset this looks ok.  My question is whether there is a need to take this further?  For instance, if I comment out the route so it theoretically no longer exists, Postman returns a Laravel error

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Now it is very unlikely that my route would disappear, but what happens if the server went down or something?  Do I want a Laravel error to be displayed to the API users, or is there some way I can handle this?

Really I am looking for advice as to the best way to handle errors within my API.

Thanks

Comment: I can't get your question? What is the issue here? Also if the server is down, Laravel is down, you need some low level error handling.

Comment: I am really after all the different types of errors I should handle.  As an example, I gave the incorrect route, which displays a Laravel error within postman.

Comment: Laravel by default has a very good error handler that handles mostly all errors. This is very broad and opinionated question. Please read the guide on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

Best way of crate API
  Add route in routes.php

```
 'api' => 'APIController',
```

Add login api in APIController.php

```
 public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
    $response = "";
    $error_message = "";

    $request->headers->set('content-type','application/json');
    $request_data = $request->all();

    $validator = $this->user_service->api_login_rules($request_data);
        if($validator->fails())
    {
      $errors = $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray();
      if(isset($errors['email']))
      {
        $error_message = $errors['email'][0];
      }
      else if(isset($errors['password']))
      {
        $error_message = $errors['password'][0];
      }      
      $response = ['code' => 100, 'error-message' => $error_message];  
      return response()->json(['error' => $response]);      
    }
    else
    {
      $email = $request_data['email'];
      $password = $request_data['password'];

      if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
      {
        $user_details = $this->user_service->getUserDetails($user_id);
        return response()->json($response, 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
      }
      else
      {
        $error_message = "Please enter correct password";
        $response = ['code' => 100, 'error-message' => $error_message];  
        return response()->json(['error' => $response]);
      } 
    }
```